# jQuery animate only the top of value 'height'

Tags: jquery, colors, jquery-animate, block

I recently had a similar thread about this, but now I need to animate the top of a block. 
As it is now, it animates from both bottom and top.

For example, I want it to shrink and so in order to get that I wrote:

```
$('#yellow').animate({height:'50%'},500);
```

But it shrinks both from top and bottom positions to center.

Is there a way to make it shrink by 50% only from the top position?

If it would of any help here are

CSS:

```
#yellow{
height:250px;
width:500px;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='yellow'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects

**Edited: Link Updated**

See a small Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/ZMUz9/

Answer (score 1):

you can stick your block to the bottom with some absolute positioning:

```
#yellow{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height:250px;
  width:500px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

note: it will need its container to be positioned also.

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete solution for shrinking block on the top position:

HTML:

```
<div id="yellow">sdsds</div>
```

CSS:

```
#yellow{  position:absolute;  bottom: 0;  height:200px;  width:250px;  background-color:yellow; }
```

JQuery:

```
$("#yellow").toggle(function() {
$(this).animate({
    'height': '100px'
}, 500);
```

}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'height': '200px'
    }, 500);
});

I have also created a bin with the solution, so try this on 
http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpc8